# Error preverifying class, coming while running my app

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am trying to run a sample project, but I am getting this error on the console and the app does not run.
I don't understand what this error means.

```
Packaging project ScheduleAir
C:\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack4.5.0_4.5.0.28\components\bin\rapc.exe -quiet codename=deliverables\Standard\4.5.0\scheduleair deliverables\Standard\4.5.0\scheduleair.rapc -sourceroot=C:\Documents and Settings\20041\workspace\ScheduleAir\src\com\intellisoft\schedule_air;C:\Documents and Settings\20041\workspace\ScheduleAir\src;C:\Documents and Settings\20041\workspace\ScheduleAir\res -import=C:\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack4.5.0_4.5.0.28\components\lib\net_rim_api.jar C:\Documents and Settings\20041\workspace\ScheduleAir\bin
Error preverifying class com.intellisoft.schedule_air.AppSettingScreen
    VERIFIER ERROR com/intellisoft/schedule_air/AppSettingScreen.()V:
Illegal type in constant pool
Error!: Error: preverifier failed: C:\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack4.5.0_4.5.0.28\components\bin\preverify.exe -d C:\DOCUME ...
Packaging project ScheduleAir failed (took 0.437 seconds)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be related to compiler target level in your Eclipse? For BB it should be set to 1.3, while by default Eclipse sets it to 1.5/1.6. Check ["More detail on preverification errors ?"](http://eclipseme.723695.n2.nabble.com/More-detail-on-preverification-errors-td950938.html) for details.

Comment: Thank u very much,but application is not run.

Comment: Of course, if this is not a solution, this answer should be unchecked from being such.

Answer (score 1):

You must set JAVA_HOME in your system environment variables

Comment: There is an accepted answer with a different solution.. Did you run into a similar error and did this work for you? Please elaborate.

Comment: yes, i also got this error. i've already try to change the compiler compliance setting to 1.3, no use. for now set the variable works for me